# Equals sign magically appears in message sending to pager

Tags: c#, email, mime, quoted-printable

I am sending a mail to an email address which forwards messages to a pager. The message I am sending is

> "Oth info; Thankyou testing now complete just be aware that 34a door
>   will open and shut when pager messages are sent with the CFSRES lt1".

but client receives it on his pager as

> "Oth info; Thankyou testing now complete just be aware that 34a door
>   will op= en and shut when pager messages are sent with the CFSRES
>   lt1".

Does anyone know why the equals sign shows up in `open changed to op= en`. I know that special characters may some times be changed, like spaces can become `%20`, but *open* does not contain any special character, so as far as I know, nothing should happen to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I search for net and found the solution, this [links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8057072/send-plain-text-email-and-getting-0d-0a-in-email-response-from-server) solve my problem. Here is some userfull  code, i need to provide the CreateAlternateViewFromString.

```
MailMessage emailmsg = new MailMessage("from@address.co.za", "to@address.co.za")
emailmsg.Subject = "Subject";
emailmsg.IsBodyHtml = false;
emailmsg.ReplyToList.Add("from@address.co.za");
emailmsg.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
emailmsg.HeadersEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
emailmsg.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
emailmsg.Body = null;

var plainView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(EmailBody, emailmsg.BodyEncoding, "text/plain");
plainView.TransferEncoding = TransferEncoding.SevenBit;
emailmsg.AlternateViews.Add(plainView);

SmtpClient sSmtp = new SmtpClient();
sSmtp.Send(emailmsg);
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a sign of [Quoted-printable encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable)

> QP works by using the equals sign "=" as an escape character. It also limits line length to 76, as some software has limits on line length.

So you may try to split the message into multiple lines in an attempt to prevent escape characters being added by the forwarder.

Comment: Thanks i think it will help, I will mark it as answer if it works

Comment: No, i added the \n after 72 digit but still had the same issue

Comment: I find this link http://www.motobit.com/util/quoted-printable-encoder.asp. And is shows if i make new line after 69 characters then it should not add extra = sign, i implement it and will send for testing. I will let you knwo if it works

Comment: it didn't work for me, when i added new line charater \n\r, then user starts receiving extra characters =OD=OA in thier message.